# How to connect with .NET app via LAN in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to preview .NET application via LAN (using Phone). App is running via Visual Studio, and in previous wersion .NET (like .NET 3 - now using .NET 6) i use code

```
webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
          .UseUrls("https://localhost:5001", "https://odin:5001");
```

and my app was visible from other devices in LAN network via https://ip:5001 (where ip was ip device where i run app from visual studio). Now if i try using code like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://localhost:7204", "https://odin:7204");
```

my web app is not visible from other debices in lan using https://ip:7204

**Edit:**

I found that .NET 6 .net 6 does not use UserUrls() method any more, but i don't find alternative

Comment: what if you change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` in C# server code?

Comment: I change `builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://localhost:7204", "https://odin:7204");` to `builder.WebHost.UseUrls("https://0.0.0.0:7204", "https://odin:7204");` and got this same problem

Comment: it may be due to network restrictions of port, you can validate it by `telnet ip port`, comparing the two ports. it may be settings of firewall or the router.